# LDAP-Server implementation with Delphi

Tags: delphi, ldap

Does anyone have information on developing a LDAP server in Delphi?

I have a multi-function printing device that needs to authenticate a user over LDAP. There are a set of rules that should be checked before the approval can be given to the user to print.

These rules need to be implemented server side, so that the printer ldap client can query the server for authorisation.

Comment: suggestion: change the question title to indicate that it is about LDAP servers (not clients)

Comment: Question adjusted, thank you.

Comment: Why don't you use an already existing LDAP server? Being an LDAP client can be easyt enough, implementing a full LDAP server can be quite complex, and require a fair understanding of the protocol. If the printer is connected to a Windows machine (you're using Delphi, right?), or if a network one accessed through a Windows print server, Windows itself can let you configure who can print to the printer and when.

Answer (score 3):

1. Project JEDI API Library has JwaWinLDAP unit.
2. There's open source project called [LDAP Admin](http://sourceforge.net/projects/ldapadmin) which's written in Delphi, it will help you to get started.
3. Look at this article [Active Directory Service Interfaces](http://www.agnisoft.com/white_papers/active_directory.asp), with ADSI service you can talk with LDAP.
4. You can import com library `activeds.dll`, and use it with Delphi.

Comment: +1 ... just curious, is #4 a server component? It seems like a Active Directory LDAP client wrapper library to me.

Answer (score 1):

The light-weight **[Ararat Synapse TCP/IP library](http://www.ararat.cz/synapse/doku.php/features)** (for Delphi and Free Pascal) includes LDAP client support.

Answer (score 1):

As far as I know, there is no LDAP server implementation for Delphi. Even commercial libraries like [IP*Works!](http://www.nsoftware.com/ipworks/components.aspx) only contain LDAP clients.

If you need a native Windows LDAP server, which is compact and does not require the full Microsoft Windows Server license, maybe ADAM / AD LDS is an option. It is available from Microsoft for Windows 7 [here](http://www.microsoft.com/downloads/details.aspx?displaylang=de&FamilyID=a45059af-47a8-4c96-afe3-93dab7b5b658). (all Microsoft Server editions include Active Directory Services, supporting LDAP, Kerberos and other standards).

Comment: I am fine with implementing on a full windows server license. What do I need to do?

Comment: all Microsoft Server editions include Active Directory Services, supporting LDAP, Kerberos and other standards

Comment: Ok, but would those allow me to implement a server instance?

Comment: "all Microsoft Server editions" but Web Server ones - which does not include AD.

Answer (score -1):

I dont know about LDAP with Delphi but I found these:
 - [Delphi LDAP Support by Christopher Burke](http://cc.embarcadero.com/item/16879)
 - [Delphi LDAP Authentication Component](http://www.freemeg.com/index.php?option=com_content&task=view&id=136&Itemid=75)

Comment: It seems these are both clients again. I need a server component.